# More than one css rule

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have:

`@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none), (-ms-high-constrast:avtive) { css code here }`

and I want it to by also with:

`@media only screen and (max-width:768px){}`

Is that possible in CSS

Comment: Not sure but wouldn't this work?

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (-ms-high-contrast:none), (-ms-high-constrast:avtive) { css code here }

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nico Shultz:

Not sure but wouldn't this work?

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (-ms-high-contrast:none), (-ms-high-constrast:avtive) { css code here }